# linux watch banner on refreshed output

Tags: linux, banner, watch

I would like to run something like this:

```
watch banner `my command`
```

The problem is - my command is evaluated only once, and I wanted it to evaluated each time...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the backticks:

```
watch banner \`my command\`
```

.

Comment: @dudiamar I checked your profile and saw that on most of your questions the accepted answers have no up-votes. I'm not begging for an upvote (at least not only for me, but also for the others) but on SO in general a good answer should be upvoted by everyone who likes it, ie, you and everyone else.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, noted... I didn't think of that - i thought accepting is good enough. Thanks.